# Countdown Timer Ends Meessage

Tags: javascript, timer, countdowntimer

A few days ago, I created countdown timer by watching a video on YouTube. The countdown timer is completely perfect but one thing is missing from it. When the timer goes to the zero it will hide from the page.

I want to show some text when timer ends. Like if timer goes to zero then timer hides and show this message "You are too late. Stay with us".

This is a .js code in which I need some modification.

```
const dayDisplay = document.querySelector(".days .number");
const hourDisplay = document.querySelector(".hours .number");
const minuteDisplay = document.querySelector(".minutes .number");
const secondDisplay = document.querySelector(".seconds .number");

const countdownContainer = document.querySelector(".countdown-container");

const endDate = new Date("August 04 2020 10:38:00");
let saleEnded = false;

const updateTimer = () => {

if(countdownContainer) {

let currentDate = new Date();
let difference = endDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();

if (difference <= 1000) {
    saleEnded = true;
}

const second = 1000;
const minute = second * 60;
const hour = minute * 60;
const day = hour * 24;

let newDay = Math.floor(difference / day);
let newHour = Math.floor((difference % day) / hour);
let newMiute = Math.floor((difference % hour) / minute);
let newSecond = Math.floor((difference % minute) / second);

dayDisplay.innerText = newDay < 10 ? "0" + newDay : newDay;
hourDisplay.innerText = newHour < 10 ? "0" + newHour : newHour;
minuteDisplay.innerText = newMiute < 10 ? "0" + newMiute : newMiute;
secondDisplay.innerText = newSecond < 10 ? "0" + newSecond : newSecond;
  };
};

setInterval(() => {
   if (!saleEnded) {
   updateTimer();
 } else {
   countdownContainer.style.display = "block";
 }
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: Modify the else statement when `saleEnded` is true?

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
 setInterval(() => {
     if (!saleEnded) {
    updateTimer();
 } else {
   countdownContainer.style.display = "block";
   countdownContainer.innetHTML="You are too late. Stay with us";
 }
 }, 1000);
```